# Is this construct 'acting opposite to' idiomatic?

Tags: phrase-usage

Consider this expression

> He has been acting very weird lately. He **is acting opposite to how he usually does**.

What I am trying to say here is that 'He is usually very calm and relaxed, but he has been very very tensed lately.' So is the second expression idiomatic in the given context.

Comment: I don't think this particular adverbial use of *opposite* is very "idiomatic". But the two sentences as given convey nothing at all about *how* he's actually acting. Or indeed, how he normally acts - all we know is he's acting very differently. I think most native speakers would explicitly mention *both* behaviours, whilst pointing out that they are "opposites". Perhaps *"He seems very tense lately - the complete opposite of his normal relaxed behaviour"*.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it's probably better to say:

> He is acting the opposite of how he usually does.